# How do I write a temporary .htaccess redirect that will pass along AdWords parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, parameter-passing, google-ads-api

I have a regular home page:
www.website.com/

And a 2nd home page that receives traffic from AdWords:
www.website.com/home

How do I write a redirect that will temporarily redirect traffic from /home to / and pass along the various AdWords parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this simple rewrite rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [L,NC]
```

Original query parameters available with `/home` URI will be automatically carried forward to `/`.

Comment: The question mark is working for me. Oddly, I have to include several variations of home to get it to work:RewriteRule ^home/?$      / [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ^home/$          / [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/home$          / [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ^home$          / [L,R=302,QSA]